# Finding eigenvectors with complex eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have trouble with how to find eigenvectors when you have a complex eigenvalue

For example the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here you get the eigenvalues $-1$ and $ \pm i$

Where do i go from here to find a eigenvector. The solution says it should be the 2x1 matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\pm i \\
-2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The eigenvalues you listed there are not correct. For the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -2 & -2\end{pmatrix}$, the characteristic equation is $z^{2}+2z + 2 = 0$, i.e. $(z+1)^2 =-1$, so the eigenvalues (which are roots of the characteristic equation) are $\boxed{-1\pm i}$ (which is the correct way to write them).

Comment: The solution says -2 and not 2 in row 2

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: The determinant for the matrix is -1 +- i

Comment: Using det(A-λI) where A is the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$You use the same procedure to find the eigenvectors as in the real case, just now you may have to use complex number arithmetic.

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}.$ I'll get you started on how to find the eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $-1+i$. As usual, these are found by solving the equation $(A - (-1+i)I)\x = \mathbf{0}$. Thus we solve the linear system

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}0-(-1+i) & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -2-(-1+i) & 0\end{array}\right),$$
that is,
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}1-i& 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1-i& 0\end{array}\right).$$

Can you solve this (if not, the first step would be to practise complex number arithmetic and row reductions with complex numbers)?

Comment: Thanks alot, but that is after that i have trouble. I have solved for -1-i too and get the same only with +i instead of - but i dont know how to make a vector out of this.

Comment: Appreciate your help with the matrix, but seems like that is understood

Comment: When i get the real eigenvalues i can easy solve with the free variables, but here i have noone.

Comment: wow, i am dumb, understanding it now. Thanks again. I just solve for both -1+i and -1-i at the same time and take the determinant at usually.

Comment: OK so in this case, note row 2 must be a multiple of row $1$ if the eigenvalue calculations so far have been done correctly, so you can ignore row 2 (you can and should be able to verify that row $2$ is $\frac{-2}{1-i}$ times row 1). Now in row 1, the second column is non-leading, so you can set $y$ to a free parameter, say $\boxed{y = \alpha}$ where $\alpha \in \Bbb{C}$. Then you get from row 1 that $(1-i)x + y =0$, so $x = -\frac{y}{1-i} = -\frac{1}{2} (1+i)y  \Rightarrow \boxed{x = -\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\alpha}$.

Comment: So the eigenspace in this case is set of all vectors of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\alpha \\ \alpha\end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=  \alpha \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$ where $\alpha\in \Bbb{C}$. By taking $\alpha =2$ as a convenient value, you can find that one eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix} -1-i\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: By the way, with enough practice, you should be able to do this one by inspection. By inspection (picking convenient values) a solution to the equation from row 1 occurs by setting $y = 1-i$ and $x=-1$, so an eigenvector here is $\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1-i\end{pmatrix}$ (much faster than using full Gaussian elimination or free variables!). Since the eigenspace is one-dimensional here (we know this e.g. since the eigenvalues are distinct), there are no other linearly independent eigenvectors for this eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

You do it just as you would for real eigenvalues.

For instance, if you want an eigenvector corresponding to the eigen value $-1+i$, you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}y=(-1+i)x\\-2x-2y=(-1+i)y,\end{array}\right.$$you will get that the solutions are the vectors of the form $\bigl((1+i)x,-2x\bigr)$. In particular, $(1+i,-2)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1+i$.